# How much job scheduling overhead is there in PBS Pro?

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, pbs

I am using PBS Pro to schedule 42 jobs each requires around 5 seconds to complete the job. With one resource it should require 210 seconds, if I have 15 resources available then it should complete that execution in 14 seconds. But it is getting completed in around 30 seconds, should I consider around 16 seconds are required for job scheduling and result writing for 42 jobs by PBS Pro or there may be some other issue.